# WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter configure for overlapping authorities

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-rest

I have implemented `UserDetailsService` to return instances of `UserDetails` with `SimpleGrantedAuthority` for my Spring Boot REST service. I have 3 price pages, two granting access to specific endpoints and the third granting access to all endpoints.

I have configured my `WebSecurityConfig` as follows. The two specific privileges work - only they can be used to access those endpoints. However the third privelage which should grant the client access to all endpoints returns a 403 forbidden.

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(“/**/foo/**”).hasAuthority(“foo”).and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(“/**/moo/**”).hasAuthority(“moo”).and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(“/**/**”).hasAuthority(“admin”)
}
```

I have tried reordering the definitions and also tried `anyRequest` but they do not work.

Answer (score 0):

[`HttpSecurity#authorizeRequests()`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.3.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html#authorizeRequests--) javadoc says:

> Note that the matchers are considered in order. Therefore, the following is invalid because the first matcher matches every request and will never get to the second mapping:
>
> ```
> http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasRole("USER").antMatchers("/admin/**")
>                 .hasRole("ADMIN")
> ```

---

Maybe you want:

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/foo/**").hasAnyAuthority("admin", "foo").and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/moo/**").hasAnyAuthority("admin", "moo").and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("admin");
}
```

Or, set [`RoleHierarchy`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html5/#authz-hierarchical-roles):

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable()
        .httpBasic().and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/foo/**").hasAuthority("foo").and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/moo/**").hasAuthority("moo").and()
        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("admin");
}

@Bean
RoleHierarchyVoter roleVoter(final RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy) {
    return new RoleHierarchyVoter(roleHierarchy);
}

@Bean
public RoleHierarchy roleHierarchy() {
    final Map<String, List<String>> hierarchyMap = new HashMap<>();
    hierarchyMap.put("admin", List.of("foo", "moo"));
    final String roleHierarchy = RoleHierarchyUtils.roleHierarchyFromMap(hierarchyMap);

    final RoleHierarchyImpl ret = new RoleHierarchyImpl();
    ret.setHierarchy(roleHierarchy);
    return ret;
}
```